# A one-dimensional Peano continuum that is not embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: general-topology, dimension-theory-analysis

I am looking for a continuous function $f\colon I\to X$ from the unit interval $I=[0,1]$ into a Hausdorff space $X$ such that its image $f(I)$ has dimension one and cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$. Hausdorff spaces which are continuous images of $I$ are sometimes referred to as Peano continua. Every such space can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. It is not difficult to find a one-dimensional Peano continuum that can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^2$ but not into $\mathbb{R}$ (a circle), or one that can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ but not into $\mathbb{R}^2$ (any non-planar finite graph). As any finite graph can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ (using so called [book embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_embedding)), I am curious whether there exist a one-dimensional Peano continuum that cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Actually, my claim that every Peano continuum can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is wrong. Consider gluing together points $0$ and $2^{-n}$ for all $n\in\omega$ and let $q$ be the quotient mapping. Then $q(I)$ is the "rose with infinitely many petals", has a point of uncountable character, is not metrizable and hence cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^k$ for any $k\le\omega$. This example also answers my question. On the other side, if $f(I)$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ then it must be metrizable and so the Embedding Theorem from Henno's answer applies.

Comment: A Peano continuum is by definition metrisable: a metric locally connected continuum. (continuum  = compact connected Hausdorff space). Or equivalently, a Hausdorff image of $[0,1]$ (which is also always metrisable).

Comment: The first sentence of this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_(topology)) admits also a definition without metrizability. I must however confess that I was a bit confused when asking the question, now the things are more clear to me. Thank you!

Comment: Your “rose” space is a metrisable continuum, BTW. It’s a Hausdorff image of $[0,1]$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: "Rose" is not metrizable, as it is not first countable. A similar space called "Hawaian earring" is. Both spaces can be defined as the same subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, where "Hawaian earring" is equipped with the subspace topology, while the topology of "rose" is coarser.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ with the integers identified to a point is not first countable, but the space you defined above as the quotient of $[0,1]$ **is** first countable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma You are right! Also, the following holds: "The continuous image of a compact metric space in a Hausdorff space is metrizable." (Willard 1970, p. 166). I hope that this time things are *really* more clear to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any separable metrisable space of dimension 1 (all standard dimension functions  will do, covering or inductive, they all coincide for separable metric spaces, like Peano continua) has an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$. (This is Nöbeling's embedding theorem). It can be generalised to $n$ and $2n+1$ in fact. See Engelking, *Theory of Dimensions, finite and infinite* Thms 1.11.4 and 1.11.5.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference. It seems that the proof uses a category argument. It is really interesting!

Comment: @PeterElias Glad I could help, it's certainly a classic argument that ought to better known, one idea is that embeddings are dense among all maps, using Baire arguments. It gets more complicated for non-metric spaces, though.

Comment: The Embedding Theorem actually does not answer my question, since a Peano continuum need not to be metrizable. See my comment below the question.